# Trying to implement time constraint in subprocess

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm coding an optimization using optuna. Throughout, I'm using spectral clustering, the parameters of which are also to be optimized.

As it turns out, the clustering can take at times up to thirty minutes to finish, or even longer. That's too long for me. For this case, I want to implement a time constraint, which should limit the time the clustering is allowed to take for its calculations.

As far as I know, the Spectral Clustering library from `sklearn.cluster` has no inherent option to interrupt the computations upon meeting certain conditions. Therefore I'm trying to interrupt the computations by different means. Specifically, I'm trying to use multiprocessing.

The idea is, that I define a threshold-time and periodically check if the elapsed time of my current trial exceeds it. The clustering, which I outsource into a subprocess, shall be aborted by terminating the subprocess if the condition is met.

I have this so far:

```
from sklearn.cluster import SpectralClustering as SpecClust
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
from umap import UMAP
import optuna



def run_clustering(spec_obj, input1, input2, output_queue):
    y_pred_train = spec_obj.fit_predict(input1)
    y_pred_val = spec_obj.fit_predict(input2)
    
    # Put the results into the output queue
    output_queue.put((y_pred_train, y_pred_val))



def objective(trial):
        
    try:
        # part where I define range in which the variables (variable_opt) shall be searched
        ...
 
    
        umap = UMAP(variable_opt)
        spec = SpecClust(variable_opt)
        umap.fit(x_train)
        
        
        # transform train and val dataset
        transform1 = umap.transform(x_train)
        transform2 = umap.transform(x_val)
        
        
        # Create a queue for storing the results
        output_queue = mp.Queue()
        
        
        # Create a separate process for running the clustering
        clustering_process = mp.Process(target=run_clustering, args=(spec, transform1, transform2, output_queue))
        
        # Start the clustering process
        clustering_process.start()
        
        # Start the timer to measure elapsed time
        timelimit_start = time.time()
              
        # Monitor elapsed time and check if it exceeds the threshold
        while clustering_process.is_alive():
            timelimit = time.time() - timelimit_start
            if limit > 600:  # 10 minutes threshold
                clustering_process.terminate()  # Terminate the clustering process
                break
        
        
        # Get the results or assign a default value if the timelimit was exceeded
        if clustering_process.exitcode == 0:
            y_pred_train, y_pred_val = output_queue.get()  # Retrieve the computed y_pred_train and y_pred_val
        else:
            trial.set_user_attr('train_acc', -1000000)
            trial.set_user_attr('val_acc', -1000000)
 
        
        # code to compute the accuracies for training and validation dataset        
        ...
        
        # Store the training and validation accuracies in the user_attrs attribute of the trial object
        ...


    except ValueError:
        trial.set_user_attr('train_acc', train_acc)
        trial.set_user_attr('val_acc', val_acc)

    
    # Elapsed time for the trial
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    
    # Calculate the total time for all trials completed so far
    total_time = total_time + elapsed_time
    
    # Print the elapsed time and total time
    ...


    return val_acc


timeout = 7200

# Create a study object and optimize the objective function
study = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize')
study.optimize(objective, timeout=timeout)
```

However, I get a number of errors when I'm executing this code. First of, for some reason two studies are started.

```
[I 2023-05-16 14:07:12,968] A new study created in memory with name: no-name-b141364b-b65b-4cf8-90b1-663337bdddcf

[I 2023-05-16 14:14:00,396] A new study created in memory with name: no-name-a5922d4c-6a02-457d-89c3-0caea5148daa
```

This never happens when I don't use the "subprocess" approach.

And these are the errors I get when running the code:

```
[W 2023-05-16 14:16:58,868] Trial 0 failed with parameters: {'n_neighbors': 225, 'min_dist': 0.2630403057529896, 'n_components': 10, 'metric': 'minkowski', 'affinity': 'neirest_neighbors', 'n_neighbors_spec': 15, 'eigen_solver': 'arpack', 'assign_labels': 'discretize', 'gamma': 6.536977432434881} because of the following error: RuntimeError('\n        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the\n        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.\n\n        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your\n        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom\n        in the main module:\n\n            if __name__ == \'__main__\':\n                freeze_support()\n                ...\n\n        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program\n        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.').

RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

[W 2023-05-16 14:16:58,870] Trial 0 failed with value None.

RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

And additionally, the script never finishes.

Can someone help me locate and debug the error? Is this approach perhaps just not viable and there are easier ways to go about it? If so, please tell me.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I see this line `study = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize')` is outside of any function and not guarded by `if __name__ == '__main__':`. Be aware this can cause subprocesses to run this code multiple times if using the spawn start method. (This is the default on Windows and OS X.)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm using Windows. I'll follow your advice and test if `if __name__ == '__main__':` works for me.